# Return substring of Core Data attribute using NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a `NSString` as an attribute of my `NSManagedObject`: 'YYYY-MM-DD'. I would like to setup a `NSFetchRequest` that returns just a substring of the attribute.

Is this possible in IOS 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can setup your fetch request to return an array of dictionaries where each dictionary will contain only the single key and value pair and then iterate over the array to create your list of substrings.

Alternatively, add another attribute that holds the substring and update and save it each time the main string changes.

Comment: Thanks @Wain (for answer and edits). When modeling the core data I have the trade off of data vs. function issue here. The app is in production and I am still hesitant to get into core data migration at the moment. I will manage the result set content post fetch and pre-use.